# Как реализовать междоменную авторизацию на Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Есть около 100 доменов, ссылающихся на 1 проект на laravel
Возможно ли реализовать автоматическую авторизацию на всех доменах сразу (При авторизации на 1 сайте, автоматически авторизируешся на всех 100)

Comment: А домены разные или поддомены одного домена?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan Все домены разные

Comment: Тогда смотреть в сторону SSO токена, через тот же jwt к примеру.

Answer (score 0):

Как я решил на данный момент

В таблицу `users` добавил два новых столбика - `auth_token`(для токена), `auth_date`(для даты получения токена)

Добавил новый `Middleware` - `Cors.php` он нужен, чтобы мы могли принимать запросы с любых доменов

Содержание - `Cors.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    }
}
```

Добавил два маршрута:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function () {
    Route::get('/auth/user', 'HomeController@authUser');//Для данного маршрута применяем middleware - cors(по данному адресу можно получить доступ с любого сайт)
});
Route::post('/api/auth/user/get', 'HomeController@authUserGet');
```

`HomeController`:

```
    public function authUser() { // В данной функции проверяем авторизирован ли пользователь на основном сайте и если он авторизирован, мы генерируем токен и записываем его в таблицу и выводим токен
        if(Auth::user()) {
            $user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            if($user) {
                $token = sha1(time());
                $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
                User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update([
                    'auth_token' => $token,
                    'auth_date' => $date
                ]);
                echo $_GET['callback']."({token:'$token'});";
            }
        } else {
            echo $_GET['callback']."({token:''});";
        }
    }
    public function authUserGet(Request $request) { // В этой функции мы получаем сгенерированный токен и по нему ищем пользователя в таблице, если находим, то проверяем, чтобы дата выпуска не превышала 60 секунд и авторизируем 
        $token = $request->input('token');
        $rez['rez'] = 0;
        if($token) {
            $user = User::where('auth_token', $token)->first();
            if($user) {
                if($user->auth_date) {
                    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $time_one_min = strtotime($date) + 60;
                    $time_one_min_minus = strtotime($date) - 60;
                    $time_token = strtotime($user->auth_date);
                    if($time_one_min_minus <= $time_token and $time_token <= $time_one_min) {
                        Auth::login($user);
                        $rez['rez'] = 1;
                        $user->auth_token = NULL;
                        $user->auth_date = NULL;
                        $user->save();
                    } else {
                        $rez['rez'] = 'Время токена истекло';
                    }
                } else {
                    $rez['rez'] = 'Не верный токе #3';
                }
            } else {
                $rez['rez'] = 'Не верный токе #2';
            }
        } else {
            $rez['rez'] = 'Не верный токе';
        }
        return $rez;
    }
```

И в самый низ шаблона добавляем сам скрипт отправки запросов

```
@guest
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://site.ru/auth/user', // Отправляем запрос на основной сайт, для проверки авторизирован на нем или нет
                dataType: 'JSONP',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data.token) { // Если авторизирован, берем токен
                        axios({
                            method: 'post',
                            url: '/api/auth/user/get',
                            params: { token: data.token }
                        }).then((response) => {
                            if(response.data.rez == 1) {
                                location.reload();
                            } else {
                                console.log(response.data.rez);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@endguest
```

В чем минусы данного способа -

- По данному адресу может обратится любой сайт - https://site.ru/auth/user
- Может так получится, что будут сгенерированы одинаковые токены и все сломается
- И самая главная проблема, что для данного метода, должен быть 1 главный сайт, то есть если Вы авторизированы на главном сайте, то при заходе на любой другой, авторизация происходит автоматический